# UnmarshalException: unexpected element while parsing xml of referenced type

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, unmarshalling

**The Exception:**

> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://xxx.com/xxxServices/response", local:"A"). Expected elements are <{http://xxx.com/xxxServices/common/acknowledgement}I>

**XSD used to generate java classes using xjc:**

```
<xs:import namespace="http://xxx.com/xxxServices/common/acknowledgement" schemaLocation="../common_acknowledgement_v1.0.xsd"/>  
<xs:element name="A" type="abr:AType">  
</xs:element>  
</xs:schema>
```

**Sample XML I'm trying to parse:**

```
<ns0:A xmlns:ns0="http://xxx.com/xxxServices/response" xmlns:ns1="http://xxx.com/xxxServices/common/acknowledgement">  
 <ns1:I  UID="24" Type="Sequential"/>  
 <ns1:S>  
 <ns1:Date  Year="2012" Month="05" Day="15"/>  
 <ns1:Time  Hour="3" Minute="31" Second="54"/>  
 </ns1:S>  
 <ns1:AAck>  
 <ns1:I  UID="24" Type="Sequential"/>  
 <ns1:B>eDUA</ns1:B>  
 <ns1:AckResult>Received</ns1:AckResult>  
 <ns1:P>47</ns1:P>  
 </ns1:AAck>  
 </ns0:A>
```

I have using `JAXBIntrospector` to do the unwrapping from `unmarshal()`.

Also, I've noticed that jaxb is putting the @XmlRootElement tag over another class that is generated `Ack` rather than over `AType` which actually should be the RootElement. I've removed the annotation from over `Ack` to `AType` & I checked with:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="A", namespace="http://xxx.com/xxxServices/response")
```

&

```
@XmlRootElement(name="AType")
```

I've also checked with `@XmlRootElement` over `Ack` like the way it was generated. Where & What am I doing!